# Calling a method from a different class

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to call search recursively either using search with the rootNode (which is BSTN) which gives me an error saying wrong type or calling getNode (error saying undefined for type BST) with a subtree of rootNode which gives me an error as well stating that I have the wrong type

```
package sizebst;



public class sizeBST {
sizeBSTN rootNode;

public SizeBST(BSTN root){
    rootNode =  root;
}



public boolean search(int target){
    //isn't complete but I want to recrusively search the tree calling methods from the other class
            getNode(rootNode.LSubtree, target);

}
```

This is the method I want to call getNode from.

```
package sizebst;


public class SizeBSTN {
SizeBSTN LSubtree;  
SizeBSTN RSubtree;  
int data; 
int size; 


public SizeBSTN(int data){
    LSubtree = null;
    RSubtree = null;
    this.data = data;
    size = 1;
}




public static SizeBSTN getNode(SizeBSTN node, int target){
// isn't working yet but it finds a node and returns it.




    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getNode` is `static` method from `SizeBSTN` class try

```
SizeBSTN.getNode(rootNode.LSubtree, target);
```

instead

```
getNode(rootNode.LSubtree, target);
```

---

Other way is to static import this method with

```
import static sizebst.SizeBSTN.getNode;
```

now you can call it without class reference.

Comment: I have tried that already, but now that works when it didn't before. Can you explain why>

Comment: @PaulthePirate It works because all static methods are called via its class if you call them from outside of its class. I have no idea why it didn't work for you earlier. Maybe you didn't compile SizeBSTN source code? Maybe you misspelled something. Hard to say.

Comment: @PaulthePirate you really need to start using some IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans and get your code automatically indented. Take a look here http://pastebin.com/Hz7qhzUK. You will see that last `else` is not connected with any `if`. Also you have `;` right after `if` which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: It was the semicolon. Sorry I am dyslexic and always see past those things. I use eclipse and it does  indent automatically I just don'tknow how to maintain that here.

Comment: Press `ctrl`+`shift`+`F` in eclipse to correctly format your code, then just copy-paste it in your post, then if code needs additional formatting on SO use `{}` on your code.